# Selenium select only direct children of WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Is there any way to do something like:

```java
webElement.findElements(By.cssSelector("> li");
```

I'm trying to get the direct children of an WebElement object.

I know about the css selector "parent > children" and it works as expected, but my case is different.

For example:

```html
<ul class="x">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```java
List<WebElement> webElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.x > li"));
```

returns only the direct sub-children of ul tag.
The size of the List is 2.
But I have the next use case:

```java
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.x"));
webElement.findElements(By.cssSelector("li");
```

The problem here is that this code returns all 'li' web elements and not only the direct children. The size of the List is 3 this time.

I tried this:

```java
webElement.findElements(By.cssSelector("> li");
```

but this throws an error

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use xpath:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.x"));
webElement.findElements(By.xpath("./li");
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Do you think there is a way to do this using css selectors?